# Why is $\nabla \cdot u=0$? (If $u=v\cos(k\cdot x)$)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, spheres, divergence-operator

Suppose $k\in \mathbb R^3$ and $v \in \mathbb S^2$ (2D sphere) and $k\cdot v=0$. Let $u=v\cos(k\cdot x)$, then why is $\nabla \cdot u=0$? 
To calculate the divergence, I look at one of the components $\partial_{j} u_{j}$. $$\partial_{j} u_{j}=\partial_{j} v_{j}\cos(k_{j}x_{j})-v_{j}[\partial_{j} k_{j}x_{j}\sin(k_{j}x_{j})+\partial_{j} x_{j}k_{j}\sin(k_{j}x_{j})]$$ I can see the term $k_{j}v_{j}$, which will be zero after summing since $k\cdot v=0$, but I don't know how to treat the rest.

Comment: I think you need tidy your indices first of all

Comment: @Rumplestillskin Thanks! Could you point out which part bothers you or which part do you think is wrong?

Comment: So I would only keep the $j$ index for what it is acting on the $j$th component and use dummy indices for anything else that is repeated. So in other words don’t have more than two $j$’s per term and everything else should be repeated dummy indices. Remember the left hand indices must match the right hand side and everything else is repeated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to avoid indices altogether whenever possible, and would use the product rule for divergence instead:
$$\nabla \cdot \left[f(x)v(x)\right] = \langle \nabla f(x), v(x)\rangle + f(x) \nabla \cdot v(x).$$
In particular if $v%$ is constant, the second term vanishes and you just get
$$\nabla \cdot u = v \cdot \nabla \cos(k\cdot x) = (v\cdot k) \sin(k\cdot x) = 0.$$

Comment: I think my blind spot here is why can we consider $v$ to be a constant when $v \in \mathbb S^2$?

Comment: @Cohomology Oh I'm assuming it's constant since you didn't write it as a function of $x$... if it varies with $x$ then the claim is not true (just take $v(x) = x/\|x\|$ for instance).

Comment: I don't think $v$ is necessarily a constant...

Comment: @Cohomology Well, then you should edit your question to make clear that $v(x)$ is a function of $x$. What you've currently written is that $v$ is a single vector in $S^2$. Also, unless $\nabla \cdot v(x)$ is given to be zero, the claim in your question is false.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! What I asked about appears in the following paper (first several lines on page 6). https://arxiv.org/pdf/1212.3801.pdf

Comment: @Cohomology I didn't read the whole paper but on page 6 it appears $v$ is the orientation of a plane wave; from all indications $v$ is not a function of $x$ (i.e. the plane wave is moving in straight line, not rotating).

Comment: I see! That's good enough. Thanks!